# Jquery once clicked loop two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

In my meteorjs app I have a problem. I made accordion, and when clicked it quickly open and close. I did console log and see that one click activate function two times. Here is my code:

```
<div class="rounded">
    <ul>
        {{#each tasksToDo}}
            {{>task}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>


<template name="task">
<li class="list_item">
    <divs class="editable-text-trigger">
      <span>{{> editableText collection="tasks" field="title" wysiwyg=true}}</span>
    </divs>
    <div class="editBt">
        <button class="completed">Completed</button><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

```
Template.task.onRendered(function(){
    $('.list_item').click(function(){
        $('.editBt-active').children('.editBt').hide(400);

        if(!$(this).hasClass('editBt-active')){
            if($('.list_item').hasClass('editBt-active')){
                $('.list_item').removeClass('editBt-active');
            }

            $(this).addClass('editBt-active').children('.editBt').show(400);
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('editBt-active');
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: tried this doesn't work

```
'click .list_item':function(click,task){
        $('.list_item').click(function(){
            $('.editBt-active').children('.editBt').hide(400);

            if(!$(this).hasClass('editBt-active')){
                if($('.list_item').hasClass('editBt-active')){
                    $('.list_item').removeClass('editBt-active');
                }

                $(this).addClass('editBt-active').children('.editBt').show(400);
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass('editBt-active');
            }
        });
    },  still the same
```

SECOND EDIT:

```
Template.task.events({

    'click .delete': function(){
        Meteor.call("deleteTask",this._id);
    },

    'click .list_item':function(click,task) {
        $(task.find('.editBt')).hide('.editBt');
    },

    'click .editable-text-trigger': function(click, task){
            $(task.find('.editable-text-trigger')).addClass('test');
        },

    'click .edit': function(click,task){
            $(task.find('.test')).trigger('click');
         },

    'blur .editable-text-trigger': function(blur, task){
        $(task.find('.editBt')).hide('.editBt');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On rendering a new `task` template instances, you add one more event handler to all existing `.list_item` elements (including the ones from other instances of the `task` template).

In Meteor, the 'official' way to define events handlers is this: (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events)

```
Template.task.events({
  'click .list_item': function(event, template){
        // here the handler logic
    }
});
```

It will register only one event handler for one `.list_item` element.

Comment: 'click .list_item':function(click,task){
            $('.list_item').click(function(){
                $('.editBt-active').children('.editBt').hide(400);

                if(!$(this).hasClass('editBt-active')){
                    if($('.list_item').hasClass('editBt-active')){
                        $('.list_item').removeClass('editBt-active');
                    }

                    $(this).addClass('editBt-active').children('.editBt').show(400);
                }else{
                    $(this).removeClass('editBt-active');
                }
            });
        },  still the same

Comment: You don't put `$('.list_item').click()` into the function anymore, because the code shown by Paweł already registers click handler for .list_item element. Inside the function you just put your logic for showing/hiding elements. Also be careful with searching using `$('.list_item')` and `$('.editBt-active')`, because if performs global (whole-document) search instead of local search (relative to the rendered template).

Comment: Just like Rafael said - remove `$('.list_item').click()` and also instead of `$('.list_item')` (or `$('.editBt-active')`), use `$(template.find('.list_item'))` (and `$(template.find('.editBt-active')`) in the handler logic - this way you'll only modify elements within a template.

Comment: I didn't know about that `template.find()` trick, pretty clever!

Comment: @MichelFloyd `template.find(selector)` is another way of using `Template.instance().$('selector')` ;)